# Update selected tag values in XML file using shell script

Tags: xml, shell, unix, xml-parsing

I have an XML file similar to the below format:

```
<name>property1</name>
    <fullName>property1</fullName>
    <info> #property info# </info>
    <value>
      <current>true</current>
      <default>false</default>
    </value>

<name>property2</name>
    <fullName>property2</fullName>
    <info> #property info# </info>
    <value>
      <current>true</current>
      <default>false</default>
    </value>

<name>property3</name>
    <fullName>property3</fullName>
    <info> #property info# </info>
    <value>
      <current>true</current>
      <default>false</default>
    </value>
```

The xml file contains hundreds of such properties. I want to update the value of current tag of a few properties only (say property2)  from true to false. How can I do this using Unix commands?

I'm new to Unix and I'm looking to write a Unix shell script for this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try XMLStarlet at http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that this will be useful for you:

http://www.unixcl.com/2010/01/replace-values-in-xml-using-sed-and-awk.html

Later Edit:

This will do it:

```
cat asd.xml | awk '{ x[NR] = $0 } END { for ( i=1 ; i<=NR ; i++ ) { if (x[i] ~ /<name>property2/ ) {x[i+4]="      <current>false</current>"}print x[i] }} ' > newfile.xml
```

where asd.xml is the original file, and newfile.xml the new one.
Be sure to back up the original file first!

Comment: I went through the above link before. It is mostly about changing a value globally across all occurrences in the file. I could use the /2 /3 to point out the 2nd or 3rd occurrence but as I mentioned there are thousands of such properties and I can't count the occurrence of a particular tag. Need to figure out a way to update selectively based on the property name. Thanks!

Comment: @Sourav Sorry, I made it properly, and tested it, it works for me for the example that you gave! If it works also for you, please don't forget to accept my answer!

Comment: It works fine. Though I'm looking for a solution that will update the file inline and not create a new file. Thanks, anyway! :)

Comment: @Sourav just change then the file name at the end of the command to the input file name... (newfile.xml to asd.xml)